# CSS change style a label for selected radio button

Tags: html, css, extjs

I have a generated HTML page that generates a radiogroup like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="RadioGroup6" class="component checkbox-group radio-group custom-radiobutton" data-component-type="RadioGroup">
        <div class="component field input radio" data-component-type="Field">
            <label id="Label11" for="Radio10" class="component label" data-component-type="Label">
                <input id="Radio10" type="radio" name="group" value="by_day" maxlength="" placeholder="" checked="checked" data-component-type="Radio"/>
            Label text</label>
            <span class="error-text"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- Some more radio buttons here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to change the style of the lable for the selected radio button.

I tried the following CSS code with no success.

```
.custom-radiobutton input[type="radio"]:checked~label {
    background-color: #E2EDF4;
}
```

(changing `~` to a `+` also didn't work)

And this

```
.custom-radiobutton :checked + label {
    background-color: #E2EDF4;
}
```

I have seen some answers here on Stackoverflow that use the `adjacent` selector but it doesn't seem to work on my situation. I would like to have a `no jquery` solution.

Comment: You want to access the parent, which isn't possible with CSS3.

Comment: Zeta: So it isn't possible?

Comment: Not with CSS3. Furthermore, the [`!` (subject)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#subject) selector has been dropped in the latest draft, so it won't be possible in CSS 4 :/. It is, however, possible, if you place the `input` _before_ the `label` and use the `for=…` attribute.

Comment: Zeta: The thing is, it's a generated page so it isn't easy to change the order of the tags.

Comment: In this case, a JavaScript solution might help. jQuery is not necessary if you're targetting recent browsers, just use `getElementsByTagName` or `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Zeta: Yep, Guess I have to go with javascript/jquery. A parent selector would be easy though ;) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you set the tag of your question to ExtJS, I give you an ExtJS solution.

Check out the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/l4i

Register a function on the change event of the radiobutton and you can access the labelEl which you can use the set the css class or directly change the style.

Main Code:

```
{
    xtype : "radio",
    fieldLabel : "Radio1",
    name : "myRadio",
    listeners : {
        change : me.onRadioButtonChange
    }
}
```

```
onRadioButtonChange : function(radioField) {
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(radioField.labelEl)) {
        if(radioField.checked) {
            radioField.labelEl.setStyle("font-weight", "bold");
            radioField.labelEl.addCls("custom-css-class");
        } else {
            radioField.labelEl.setStyle("font-weight", "");
            radioField.labelEl.removeCls("custom-css-class");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really close to how I solved it now ;) thanks!

Comment: Please include the essence of your code in your answer. Even though it's unlikely that the sencha link will become invalid, it's rather cumbersome to load another site.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with CSS. However you can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```js
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
  $("label").removeClass("active");
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) { $(this).parent().addClass("active"); }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #E2EDF4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="foo1">
  <input type="radio" id="foo1" name="foo"> Label 1
</label>
<label for="foo2">
  <input type="radio" id="foo2" name="foo"> Label 2
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it...

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
    color: #292321;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-border-radius:  50%;
    border-radius:  50%;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
     background-color:#292321;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span{
     background-color:#CC3300;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  -webkit-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="RadioGroup6" class="component checkbox-group radio-group custom-radiobutton" data-component-type="RadioGroup">
        <div class="component field input radio" data-component-type="Field">
            <input id="Radio10" type="radio" name="group" value="by_day" maxlength="" placeholder="" data-component-type="Radio"/>
            <label id="Label11" for="Radio10" class="component label" data-component-type="Label"><span></span>Label text</label>
            <span class="error-text"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- Some more radio buttons here -->
    </div>
</div>
```